# The term 'yar' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: reactjs, npm, web-frontend, np, yarn-v2

after installing yarn with this code  , i got this message. how should i install yarn on my project then? using windows 11.

```
npm install -g yarn

changed 1 package, and audited 2 packages in 922ms

found 0 vulnerabilities
(yar : The term 'yar' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or 
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the 
path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ yar -v)
```

i expect to install yarn in my project and nodemodule folder be not only 8 Mg...

Comment: Did you mean `yarn`?

Comment: Try using a different terminal like git bash

Comment: yes i mean yarn

Comment: i was running my project with npm. and then  i tryied to use yarn to see the difference.

Comment: i removed nod module folder... then after this (npm install -g yarn) --and i got a 8mg node module (it means it doesnt install correctly)

Comment: gi bash is the same...

Comment: Try following the instructions https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install

Comment: doesnt work for me .

Answer (score 0):

Install yarn globally

`npm install --global yarn`

Check the version

`yarn --v`

Make sure the Environment path is set correctly. If its not set, copy the location of
`users/../AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/yarn/bin`
and paste it under path in environment variables.
you might have to restart your editor though